# python /openpyxl- Totals Row not added

Tags: python, python-3.6, openpyxl

I am trying to output data generated by a python script to a xlsx-file using openpyxl.

I want to define Tables that also have a Totals row using code similar to the example from the documentation:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table, TableStyleInfo

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

data = [
    ['Apples', 10000, 5000, 8000, 6000],
    ['Pears',   2000, 3000, 4000, 5000],
    ['Bananas', 6000, 6000, 6500, 6000],
    ['Oranges',  500,  300,  200,  700],
]

# add column headings. NB. these must be strings
ws.append(["Fruit", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"])
for row in data:
    ws.append(row)

tab = Table(displayName="Table1", ref="A1:E5", totalsRowShown=True)
ws.add_table(tab)
wb.save('test_table.xlsx')
```

> However - nothing changes in the generated excel-file.
>   There is no Totals row once I open the file in Excel

I know that I still need to provide formulas for each cell in the totals row but first I need to create it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is a "bug" ticket (request) on the repo for this, the author discusses it here: [Not clear how to configure a Table Totals Row](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/791/not-clear-how-to-configure-a-table-totals)

Answer (score 4):

You need to create the totals row and the table columns manually using the exact same values as an Excel XLSX file. You can save an Excel XLSX file and examine the sheet XML and table XML so that you can determine the necessary values.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table, TableColumn, TableStyleInfo
from openpyxl.worksheet.filters import AutoFilter
from openpyxl.writer import theme, excel


def update_theme():
    color = {
        "1F497D": "44546A",
        "EEECE1": "E7E6E6",
        "4F81BD": "5B9BD5",
        "C0504D": "ED7D31",
        "9BBB59": "A5A5A5",
        "8064A2": "FFC000",
        "4BACC6": "4472C4",
        "F79646": "70AD47",
        "0000FF": "0563C1",
        "800080": "954F72"
    }

    xml = theme.theme_xml
    for original, replacement in color.items():
        xml = xml.replace(f"val=\"{original}\"", f"val=\"{replacement}\"")

    theme.theme_xml = xml
    excel.theme_xml = xml


def autosize_columns(worksheet):
    def value_of(value):
        return (str(value) if value is not None else "")

    for cells in worksheet.columns:
        length = max(len(value_of(cell.value)) for cell in cells)
        column_letter = get_column_letter(cells[0].column)
        worksheet.column_dimensions[column_letter].width = length

    return worksheet


def create_test_workbook():
    # Initialize workbook and worksheet.
    workbook = Workbook()
    properties = workbook.properties
    properties.title = "Test"
    properties.creator = None

    sheet = workbook.active
    sheet.title = "Test"

    table_name = "TestTable"

    # Add data.
    headers = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]
    sheet.append(headers)

    sheet.append(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
    sheet.append(["e", "f", "g", "h"])

    sheet.append(["Total", "", "", f"=SUBTOTAL(103,{table_name}[{headers[3]}])"])

    # Add table.
    style = TableStyleInfo(
        name="TableStyleMedium2",
        showFirstColumn=False,
        showLastColumn=False,
        showRowStripes=True,
        showColumnStripes=False
    )

    table_columns = tuple(TableColumn(id=h, name=header) for h, header in enumerate(headers, start=1))
    total_column = table_columns[0]
    total_column.totalsRowLabel = "Total"
    count_column = table_columns[3]
    count_column.totalsRowFunction = "count"

    max_column = sheet.max_column
    max_column_letter = get_column_letter(max_column)
    max_row = sheet.max_row
    table = Table(
        displayName=table_name,
        ref=f"A1:{max_column_letter}{max_row}",
        autoFilter=AutoFilter(ref=f"A1:{max_column_letter}{max_row - 1}"),
        tableStyleInfo=style,
        totalsRowShown=True,
        totalsRowCount=1,
        tableColumns=table_columns
    )

    sheet.add_table(table)

    # Adjust column sizes.
    autosize_columns(sheet)

    # Set the active cell under the table.
    active_cell = f"A{max_row + 1}"
    selection = sheet.sheet_view.selection[0]
    selection.activeCell = active_cell
    selection.sqref = active_cell

    return workbook


def main(*args):
    update_theme()

    workbook = create_test_workbook()
    workbook.save("Test.xlsx")
    workbook.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how big your data set is, but I am going to assume that the data you get is presented in the form of lists.
You can try to convert your list into a pandas dataframe, and automatically calculate the sum of all rows. Once you're done, you can save your panda dataframe as an excel.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
['Apples', 10000, 5000, 8000, 6000],
['Pears',   2000, 3000, 4000, 5000],
['Bananas', 6000, 6000, 6500, 6000],
['Oranges',  500,  300,  200,  700],
]


headers = ["Fruit", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"]

#Create panda dataframe with your data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#Rename columns
df.columns = headers
#Use Fruit column as index
df.set_index('Fruit', inplace = True)

#Calculate sum of all columns, and set index name to new variable
total = df.sum()
total.name = 'Total'
#Append into new row
df = df.append(total)

#Save to excel
df.to_excel('name.xlsx')
```

This does not solve your issue using openpyxl, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need the capabilities of excel (the dynamic calculations of subtotal when hiding/filtering) so this is not a solution for my problem but interesting nonetheless. Right now I‘m adding the results row as a normal row. This way I loose the possibility of making a structured reference to the results line making references more difficult but it’s better than nothing.

Comment: I wish to use the same feature and when I add the totalsRowCount to the table, after  when I open the file, excel tell to me that the file is corrupted